# Files no longer binding to dictionary after upgrade to 1.0.0

Tags: model-binding, asp.net-core-1.0

I have in my model:

```
public IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<IFormFile>> ZoneOfAnalysisFiles { get; set; }
```

And for the HTML:

```
 <input id="ZoneOfAnalysisFiles[@Model.Key].Key" name="ZoneOfAnalysisFiles[@Model.Key].Key" value="@Model.Value.Identification" hidden />
 <input id="ZoneOfAnalysisFiles[@Model.Key].Value" name="ZoneOfAnalysisFiles[@Model.Key].Value" type="file" multiple/>
```

This was all working fine but after upgrading to RTM (`"1.0.0-preview2-003121"`) now all the sudden it's not binding anymore. Has anyone else had this problem?